# Python Pandas Calc Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas dataframes and I am trying to join the right table on the left table where Inclination closest matches the Left tables 'Depth' from the Right Tables 'MeasuredDepth'?

Example left table  (main table)

```
index     Date_Time         Depth
6659    4/25/2017 1:26       2073.02
6660    4/25/2017 1:26       2073.287
6661    4/25/2017 1:26       2073.916
6662    4/25/2017 1:26       2074.64
6663    4/25/2017 1:26       2075.335
6664    4/25/2017 1:26       2076.044
```

Example Right table (Reference table)

```
index   MeasuredDepth   Inclination
16      1844           1.42
17      1939           1.69
18      2034           1.43
19      2128           1.39
20      2223           1.12
21      2317           1.22
22      2412           1.1
23      2600           0.56
24      2695           1.97
```

Example Result Table

```
index   DATETIME        Depth        Inclination
6659    4/25/2017 1:26      2073.02          1.43
6660    4/25/2017 1:26      2073.287         1.43
6661    4/25/2017 1:26      2073.916         1.43
...
26704   5/3/2017 23:23      2625.316         0.56
26705   5/3/2017 23:23      2626.143         0.56
26706   5/3/2017 23:24       2627.08         0.56
26707   5/3/2017 23:24      2628.056         0.56
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas-merge-asof):

```
ref_df['MeasuredDepth'] = ref_df['MeasuredDepth'].astype(float)

df_out = pd.merge_asof(main_df, ref_df, left_on='Depth',right_on='MeasuredDepth')
```

Output:

```
     index_x Date_Time     Depth  index_y  MeasuredDepth  Inclination
0  4/25/2017      1:26  2073.020       18         2034.0         1.43
1  4/25/2017      1:26  2073.287       18         2034.0         1.43
2  4/25/2017      1:26  2073.916       18         2034.0         1.43
3  4/25/2017      1:26  2074.640       18         2034.0         1.43
4  4/25/2017      1:26  2075.335       18         2034.0         1.43
5  4/25/2017      1:26  2076.044       18         2034.0         1.43
```

Comment: See the above example to see if that makes any sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best and fastest way would be to sort the values either in ascending or descending order.

```
leftTable = leftTable.sort_values('Depth')
rightTable = rightTable.sort_values('Merge')
#reindex the data
leftTable = leftTable.reset_index(drop=True)
rightTable = rightTable.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now go for the merge with the index as parameter.

```
Table = leftTable.join(rightTable, how = "outer")
```

The other alternative would be to go for an iteration method which will not only be time consuming but might also cause data loss. 
If this was an ascending sorted datframe for left table(data modified for ease).

```
index Date_Time Depth
6659 4/25/2017 1:26 20
6660 4/25/2017 1:26 21
6661 4/25/2017 1:26 23
6662 4/25/2017 1:26 24
6663 4/25/2017 1:26 27
6664 4/25/2017 1:26 28
```

And if this was an ascending sorted array for Right Table (Data Modified for ease)

```
index MeasuredDepth Inclination
16 1844 12
17 1939 20
18 2034 21
19 2128 23
20 2223 24
21 2317 27
```

They are both of equal sizes. If we used a function to measure the difference between the Depth values of each row in both tables then clearly the row with Depth 12 on the Right Table will not be appended anywhere as the criterion set is "Minimum Distance"

If you are fine with the loss of data then you can try iterating over each row and finding the best match.

Comment: An iteration method would probably work.  After the join the result table should have the same number of rows but an new column 'Inclination' where the Inclination value closest matches the corresponding 'Depth'.
Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @CodeStack82 how can the inclination closest match the Depth? Can you elaborate?

Comment: See response and image above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For example, For each Depth value in the left table I basically want to look up the similar depth range in the Right table and return the closest inclination for that depth.

The problem is the 'Depth' values in 'Left Table' are Time Series Data so I would basically get a row of values every 5 seconds. The 'Right table' 'MeasuredDepth' column values are only recorded every 95 feet. So I'm just trying to get the closest inclination value from the Right table that matches up with the more random 'Depth' value in the Left Table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fACQW.jpg)

Comment: Sorry for the confusing response, Still new to Stack Overflow